# Why did our cactus die?

Tags: diagnosis, cactus

We had a cactus named eddy and he died, he had a stretched body with a sphere on top as a head and two little spheres attached to it like eyes. He looked like Echinocereus triglochidiatus but with more smaller spines. Not taller then 25cm with a diameter of about 6cm.

We just found him with his body, the stretched bottom part all dried out. He was just fine two days ago. We watered him once a week with about 25cl. He did not get that much sun light since he was pretty far away from any windows.

We are very sad our eddy has left us but we would like to know the cause of death.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to do diagnosis even with a picture but a few things are clear from your description:

- the plant had a grafted cactus on top  (the "Sphere"). These plants depend on the health of the cactus at the base to supply water and nutrients to the graft on the top.
- if the amount of light was low then it probably did not require that much water.
- cacti can die from the inside out so they look fine until all the roots and tissue are dead and it's all over

I suggest there was too little light and too much water for a plant that requires lots of light and less water due to it being a graft.